# pass a value to a variable in javascript where these values are responses in json

Tags: javascript, json

I want to pass a value to a variable in javascript. These values are responses in json.

```
$.getJSON('url.php?id=login&email='+document.getElementById("txtemail").value+'&password='+document.getElementById("txtpassword").value, function (data) 
{   
    alert(data.status);
    alert(data.msg);
    alert(data.user_id);
    alert(data.session_id);
});
```

I want to store session_id in a variable and then have to send it to a url. How can i do this?
Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

`var ses_id = data.session_id;`

`jQuery.post("<url>?session_id="+ses_id);`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

you can use console.log to debug your javascript a little bit more efficiently. http://getfirebug.com/logging

compare this to the post of the previous poster:

```
$.getJSON('url.php', 'id=login&email='+document.getElementById("txtemail").value+'&password='+document.getElementById("txtpassword").value, 
    function (data) {   
        console.log(data);
        var session_id = data.session_id;
        $.post('url2.php', session_id, function() {
            alert('success');
        });
    }
});
```